# How to rotate a div by using two points coordinates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using div to create lines by reducing their widths. I have two random points coordinates and I want to draw a line between them using div. However, div only need one point coordinate along with their width and height for their creation and the result is always a vertical div. Is there any way to rotate a div so as to join two random points? I have tried rotate function, but it uses the specified angle.Here is the code I am using for div creation:

```js
function creatediv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity) 
{ 
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);  

    newdiv.style.width =  width + "px";     
    newdiv.style.height = height + "px";     

    newdiv.style.position = "absolute";         
    newdiv.style.left = left + "px";         
    newdiv.style.top = top + "px";  

    newdiv.style.background = "red";    
    newdiv.style.opacity = opacity;
    //newdiv.style.transform = "rotate(37deg)";
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv); 

}
```

Comment: Trigonometry problem to get the angle?

Comment: I don't understand.... you're passing `width` and defining only one coordinate point `left` , `top`. Where is your ***two points coordinates*** here? Also, why (since you use what you use) don't you pass simply the rotation parameter?!

Comment: Why can't you calculate the angle?

Comment: I do not want to calculate angle because I have to plot a huge real time data and calculation of angle will make it inefficient and inconsistent.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am searching a way to make it using two point coordinates. Currently I only know this way of passing width and height.

Comment: @HimanshuJindal what? YOu don't want to calculate the angle? Than how do you expect to rotate the DIV element if you **don't know the angle of rotation**?

Comment: basically I want to join two random points. But divs are only drawn vertically using one point.

Comment: @HimanshuJindal P.S.. just out of curiosity, why don't you use a canvas element?

Comment: I have tried canvas element. I was not able to remove a line once drawn in canvas too. I want to toggle that line on click of checkbox. I can do this by using div and reducing its opacity to zero. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: I also tried jsDraw2D library, but still, no way to remove a line once drawn.

Comment: There aren't any ways of positioning an element via 2 sets of coordinates like that. To do it with DOM nodes like that, you are going to have to calculate an angle (like answers so far do).

Comment: You can remove the lines if you draw them on a canvas. It's just a matter of saving the state of the canvas before you draw things you will want to remove and then rolling it back and redrawing things without the line you are removing. [MDN has a pretty good tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) on using canvas. Check out the [basic animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) one for the kind of stuff you need to know to do that.

Comment: @UselessCode I have tried this one too because it will be too inefficient to save state each time because I have a huge data set. Although , I am going with the calculation of angle because its the best available choice. Thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For two points •`a` and •`b` , both having `x y` coordinates

**distance**  `Math.hypot(by-ay, bx-ax)`
**degrees**   `Math.atan2(by-ay, bx-ax) * 180 / Math.PI;`

The `div` is than positioned `top,left` according to the point `a` coordinates.
The `transformOrigin`  needs to be defined as `left 50%` in order to keep the `div` point-centered:

```js
function creatediv(id, ax,ay, bx,by, size, opacity, color) { 

    var length = Math.hypot(by-ay, bx-ax),
        deg    = Math.atan2(by-ay, bx-ax) * 180 / Math.PI;

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);  
    newdiv.style.width =  length + "px";     
    newdiv.style.height = (size||2) + "px";  
    newdiv.style.left = ax + "px";   
    newdiv.style.top = ay + "px";   
    newdiv.style.background = color || "red";    
    newdiv.style.opacity = opacity || 1;
    newdiv.style.transformOrigin = "left 50%";
    newdiv.style.transform = "rotate("+ deg +"deg)";
    newdiv.style.position = "absolute";

    document.body.appendChild(newdiv); 

}


creatediv("a", 20, 20, 200, 80);
```

**Several connected lines**, and a different approach to set styles:

```js
const createLine = (options) => { 
  const opt = Object.assign({
    ax: 0,
    ay: 0,
    bx: 0,
    by: 0,
    size: 1,
    color: "#000f",
  }, options);
  
  const
    length = Math.hypot(opt.by-opt.ay, opt.bx-opt.ax),
    deg = Math.atan2(opt.by-opt.ay, opt.bx-opt.ax),
    elDiv = document.createElement('div');
    
  Object.assign(elDiv.style, {
    width: `${length}px`,
    height: `${opt.size}px`,
    left: `${opt.ax}px`,
    top: `${opt.ay}px`,
    background: opt.color,
    transformOrigin: "left 50%",
    rotate: `${deg}rad`,
    position: "absolute",
  });
  
  document.body.append(elDiv); 
}

createLine({ax:0, ay:30, bx:10, by:10});
createLine({ax:10, ay:10, bx:60, by:80, color: "#0bf"});
createLine({ax:60, ay:80, bx:110, by:50});
createLine({ax:110, ay:50, bx:160, by:70, color: "#f0b8"});
```

Comment: Thank You. I was initially afraid that calculation of angle will be complex, but the way you explained, it now seems very easy. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check angle and range between two point values and rotate it with this angle like that:

```js
   
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id', 10);
var point1x = 65;
var point1y = 45;
var point2x = 80;
var point2y = 90;

var height = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((point2x-point1x),2) + Math.pow((point2y-point1y),2));
var angleDeg = Math.atan2(point2y - point1y, point2x - point1x) * 180 / Math.PI;

newdiv.style.width = 30 + "px";
newdiv.style.height = height + "px";
newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
newdiv.style.left = point1x + "px";
newdiv.style.top = point1y + "px";
newdiv.style.borderColor = "black";
newdiv.style.borderWidth = "1px";
newdiv.style.borderStyle = "solid";
newdiv.style.background = "red";
newdiv.style.opacity = 5;
  
newdiv.style.transform = "rotate("+angleDeg+"deg)";
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

I am a little bit amateur about math functions so test it before you use it please. There may be little mistakes about angle or height of element.

Edit: Now i see that you didn't want calculate angle. I don't know if there is a proper way to do that with angle. I won't delete this solution in case of anybody want to do that with angle calculation.